# Creating user specific tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a register and login PHP script, that uses sessions and will display each users name when they log in. I also have a form that they can fill and is added to a mysql database. Is it possible so that only the user that filled in THEIR form can see it when its displayed? Currently whenever any user fills the form its displayed to every user.

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;

}


?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='fg_membersite_content'>
<h2>Product control page</h2>
<p>
Logged in as: <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName() ?>
</p>
<p>Here you can see your Current Products:</p>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("trackerweb",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name_of_Product FROM Product_Tracker");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['Name_of_Product'];
  echo "<br />";

mysql_query($query); 

}
mysql_close($con);

?>

<p>
<a href='add_customer.php'>Add a new product </a>
</p>
<p>
<a href='view.php'>View all product details</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href='login-home.php'>Home</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I only need to display the name of the product when they fill in the form on the same page.

This is the form:

```
<?php 
require_once("/extlib/vdaemon/vdaemon.php");

require_once("./core/config.php");

$_SESSION['user']= ['$fgmembersite->UserFullName'];
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #e4e4e4;
}

.form {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

.error {
    color: #AA0000
}
.controlerror {
    background-color: #ffffdd;
    border: 1px solid #AA0000;
}

.input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];

if ( $msg == '1' ) {
    echo '<p>Your information was submitted successfully.</p>';
}
?>

<form action="core/process.php" method="post" id="registration" >
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Product_Tracker" />

<p>Name of product:<input type="text" name="Name of Product" class="input" />


<p>Please select the tests that were done on the product.</p>   
<p>In Circuit Test (ICT): Yes: <input type="radio" name="ICT" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="ICT" value="no" /></p>
<p>Visual Inspection: Yes: <input type="radio" name="Visual Inspection" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="Visual Inspection" value="no" /></p>
<p>XRAY: Yes: <input type="radio" name="XRAY" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="XRAY" value="no" /></p>
<p>Automated Optical Inspection (AOI): Yes: <input type="radio" name="AOI" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="AOI" value="no" /></p>
<!--<p>Checkbox1 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox1" /> Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox2" /></p>-->



<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<p>
<a href='access-controlled.php'>Back</a>
</p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php VDEnd(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's unclear. You said you've a form that they can fill, but what they fill?

Comment: I updated to include the form, I only need to display the name of the product that they entered uniquely to their profile page.

Comment: The logic is, when they hit submit, you save those entered data in a separate table along with their unique user id. So, In the profile page, use select query with WHERE clause (like user_id==$_SESSION['id']) and retrieve everything they entered and display it. So, it will display only what that user entered.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but how would i go about doing this?

Comment: How do i create a separate table that includes the users unique id? Right now i have a table that has includes the user information when they sign up - id_user/name/password email phone number etc. I then have a different table in the same database that includes the form they fill in.

Comment: Just add a new column `user_id` in the second table where you are saving your filled data. So, use Select query like Select `column_name1, column_name2` WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']. When a user login, you save that that id to `$_SESSION` and use that information in above query.

Comment: Ive been trying to do that i added this line to the form<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="$_SESSION['user_id']" /> but in my table it doesnt display the user_id, it just says "$_SESSION['user_id'] and not their name.

Comment: @Yuva Raj Hi i got the user id to be added to my table. How would i display this now?